# Why do I need to use the VPN Client before using the remote desktop connection?

Tags: vpn, mstsc

To access a remote database, I first have to use a program called "Shrew Soft VPN Access Manager", then I go to MSTSC(remote desktop connection).

But why is that ? why can't I simply log into the remote desktop connection program?

Comment: Does this question belong on a different site?

Comment: Not my downvote, but yes, this doesn't belong on SO. Maybe [Super User](http://superuser.stackexchange.com), to which this question may get automatically migrated, but I'd suggest fleshing it out with some of your own research to ensure a good reception. What is "Shrew Soft VPN Access Manager"? What is supposed to do (show us something from its product page or documentation)? Who told you to install it?

Comment: Though it sounds like this boils down to "what is the purpose of a VPN?"

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - OK got it, I will study it! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading up on [VPN's now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).  Admittedly, this question was not well-prepared and is too vague. I will listen to Michael's advice above.

As for ShrewSoft - it may be security reasons.